# htaccess rewrite AJAX url to pretty link

Tags: ajax, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

I am working with a Wordpress theme that is driven on AJAX. A nice way to load content, but not so much for SEO purposes.

The URL's all and width the 'same' string like for example: #menu-item-44 (the only difference will be the number at the end).

For it is AJAX driven, I can not make use of Wordpress' permalink structure so my question is really, can I fix this with a rewrite in my htaccess file?

For example: www.somesite.com/#menu-item-44 becomes www.somesite.com/contact

Your help will be much appriciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite the # part of a url as it does not get sent to the server.

Look into the javascript pushstate() and googles ajax solution using hash bangs (#!)

Comment: Thanks Tiggerito for your reply! I am not really in to AJAX, so I guess I need to find myself some other theme with similar functionalities ;) Thanks again!